# How to destroy array of arrays

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2

```
myarr : array [0 .. 21] of array [0 .. 21] of TColor;
```

above is the declaration , after the use i want to destroy the array of array

```
for a := 0 to 21 do
  for b := 0 to 21 do
        myarr[a][b].destroy ;
       //myarr[a,b].destroy ;
```

both the code are giving me error ,

> E2018 Record, object or class type required (Delphi)

this is actually implemented inside a class , and i want to do this when the object of class is being destroyed

i have implemented this when a mouse click is executed the previous object(which includes this array) must be destroyed and a new object must be created.Practically when this happens the their must be no any extra memory left , but when i check this in my windows task manager for each click another 200 kb is added ,my app will do this for multiple times.

Comment: You can't and don't need to destroy an static array.

Comment: why -1 , please tell a reason

Comment: I also want to know. @vibeeshanRC, you can't destroy TColor. if it was an array of classes you can but TColor is not a class. Can you post more code?

Comment: Thanks but i thought tcolor is a class , and i have to free those objects

Comment: TColor is just an integer. It's a value type and does not need to be destroyed. For what it's worth, don't ever call Destroy, call Free instead. But that advice is for when you have an object.

Comment: @vibeeshanRC David Heffernan already gave you the answer and a tip for future, now let me give you a tip, hold CTRL key and mouse click on TColor and the IDE will take you to the declaration off the type, the same holds true for other types, suppose you have a var declaration like "var a: TStringList;", hold CTRL and mouse click on "TStringList" to find it's definition, in this way you can find out if a variable needs to be freed or not, also, you might want to use "FreeAndNil( AVARIABLE )" rather than calling ".Free"

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`TColor` is an integer type, a value type, and is not a class. Accordingly it is does not need to be freed. The definition of `TColor` is

```
TColor = -$7FFFFFFF-1..$7FFFFFFF;
```

So your array is pretty much equivlent, for the purposes of alloction, to

```
myarr: array [0..21] of array [0..21] of Integer;
```

The elements of such an array do not need to be freed. The array itself will be freed automatically, no matter where you declare it (global, local, class member, record member). It is also a value type.

The best clue that you don't need to free `TColor` is that you never created it in the first place. Allocations and deallocations are always paired.

---

As an aside, you should never call `Destroy` directly. You write `Destroy` in code only when implemented the overridden destructor for a class, i.e. like this:

```
destructor Destroy; override;
...
destructor TMyClass.Destroy;
begin
  FMyObject.Free;
  inherited;
end;
```

When you come to destroy an object you should call `Free` on it. Do **not** call `Destroy` directly. Why not? Well, `Free` is implemented like this:

```
procedure TObject.Free;
begin
  if Self <> nil then
    Destroy;
end;
```

The `if` statement means that if you have an object reference that is `nil`, then it is safe to call `Free` on it without fear of an exception being raised.

This is important in case an exception is raised in a constructor. When that happens the destructor is called. If the constructor has only partially completed, then some fields will still be `nil`. Calling `Free` allows us to write clean destructor code. Without this convenience all our destructors would look like this:

```
destructor TMyClass.Destroy;
begin
  if FMyObject3<>nil then
    FMyObject3.Destroy;
  if FMyObject2<>nil then
    FMyObject2.Destroy;
  if FMyObject1<>nil then
    FMyObject1.Destroy;
  inherited;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks , My question is actually not accurate but your answer clarified me what i have to do